# Why Twitter's favicon goes randomly black?

Tags: twitter

I noticed that for the last couple of days the Twitter's favicon goes randomly black (and I'm not the [only](https://twitter.com/rociovaldi/status/601668302704922624) [one](https://twitter.com/geospacedman/status/601786971019735040)). Is there any reason?

Comment: Although just a hunch (and I have no evidence to confirm) I would suspect they are playing about with [SVG favicons](http://caniuse.com/#feat=link-icon-svg)

Comment: I think @Barry has hit the nail on the head... and I suspect you are using Firefox (the only browser that appears to have (partial) support for SVG favicons)... https://abs.twimg.com/a/1432824385/img/t1/favicon.svg

Comment: @w3d Yep, that's right!
Didn't know that SVG images may be used as favicons, awesome. A subsidiary question would be: why it is not blue by default?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Epoc points out in a comment above; Twitter, Pinterest and some other sites are all early adopters of Apple's new pinned themed favicons. Unfortunately the new favicons hijack the existing favicon syntax which causes conflicts in Firefox as the sites are not declaring the multiple favicons in the correct order.

For more detail see the WHATWG email thread 
https://readable-email.org/list/whatwg/topic/apple-s-new-link-rel-icon-mask-not-quite-favicon-syntax-causing-problems-in-other-browsers-needs-standardization

Answer (score 1):

Yes, the black favicon is an SVG file, although SVG files don't need to be black (or even single-colored) so I'm not sure why they didn't just use their standard light blue there too unless they specifically want people to notice it.

Incidentally, Pinterest is doing the exact same thing right now too—black SVG favicon for Firefox.

These are their declarations:

```
<link rel="icon" sizes="any" mask href="https://abs.twimg.com/a/1433192681/img/t1/favicon.svg">
<link rel="icon" sizes="any" mask href="https://s-passets-cache-ak0.pinimg.com/webapp/style/app/common/images/pinterest_badge.ccdac53e.svg">
```

Comment: Daniel Holbert from Mozilla mailed about this problem in Firefox on the W3C mailing list https://lists.w3.org/Archives/Public/public-whatwg-archive/2015Jun/0011.html